# Win7 File Explorer Crashing

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash

I experienced a strange behaviour lately : whenever I try to get a specific file, Windows Explorer crashes.

By "get", i mean rename it or parent folder, delete it or parent folder, and even just right click it ! And it also make crash any program that try to use it.

After rebooting the computer, the problem is gone, but it reappear after a few (generally 8) uses of the file (by another program).

The path to this file is C:\Users\Me\.gradle\daemon\2.8\registry.bin

I get this problem because of a unknown problem debugging Android Studio ([thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34118223/3888000))

eventvwr.msc show an error when I force-close the unresponding application (sorry it's in french) :

> Nom du journal :Application  Source :       Application  Hang Date :
>   12/12/2015 14:47:29  ID de l’événement :1002  Catégorie de la
>   tâche :(101)  Niveau :       Erreur  Mots clés :    Classique 
>   Utilisateur :  N/A  Ordinateur :   Dan-PC  Description : Le programme
>   explorer.exe version 6.1.7600.16385 a cessé d’interagir avec Windows
>   et a été fermé. Pour déterminer si des informations supplémentaires
>   sont disponibles, consultez l’historique du problème dans le Centre de
>   maintenance.  ID de processus : 2a18  Heure de début :
>   01d134e2bb650bdd  Heure de fin : 11  Chemin d’accès de l’application :
>   C:\Windows\explorer.exe  ID de rapport :
>   e1110459-a0d6-11e5-ba6c-f46d041242b6
>
> XML de l’événement :
>
> ```
> <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">   
>     <System>
>     <Provider Name="Application Hang" />
>     <EventID Qualifiers="0">1002</EventID>
>     <Level>2</Level>
>     <Task>101</Task>
>     <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
>     <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-12-12T13:47:29.000000000Z" />
>     <EventRecordID>73348</EventRecordID>
>     <Channel>Application</Channel>
>     <Computer>Dan-PC</Computer>
>     <Security />   
>     </System>   
>     <EventData>
>     <Data>explorer.exe</Data>
>     <Data>6.1.7600.16385</Data>
>     <Data>2a18</Data>
>     <Data>01d134e2bb650bdd</Data>
>     <Data>11</Data>
>     <Data>C:\Windows\explorer.exe</Data>
>     <Data>e1110459-a0d6-11e5-ba6c-f46d041242b6</Data>
>     <Binary>55006E006B006E006F0077006E0000000000</Binary>   
>     </EventData> 
> </Event>
> ```

How could I unlock this file ?

### EDIT :

If I try to delete or rename this file using command console (`del registry.bin`, with admin rights), nothing happens like if the command were running for a loooong time, and I still can abort it with Ctrl+C